# How to convert *any* Python object into a string?

Tags: python, utf-8

I want to concatenate a list of various Python objects into one string. The objects can be literally anything. I thought I could simply do this using the following code:

```
' '.join([str(x) for x in the_list])
```

but unfortunately that sometimes gives me a UnicodeEncodeError:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
```

in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/1650012) I found someone who says that I need to use `.encode('utf-8')`, so I changed my code to this:

```
' '.join([x.encode('utf-8') for x in the_list])
```

But if the objects are not strings or unicodes but for example `int`s I get an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`. So this means I need to use some kind of if-statement to check what kind of type it is and how to convert it. But when should I use `.encode('utf-8')` and when should I use `str()`?

It would be even better if I could also do some kind of oneliner for this, but I wouldn't know how? Does anybody else know? All tips are welcome!

Comment: What do you want this conversion to do, aside from "produce a string"? Presumably, the result should be somehow representative of the original object, but how much does it matter exactly what string gets produced?

Comment: @user2357112 - Because it's mainly for logging purposes, it doesn't really matter too much how close it comes.

Comment: Then why not take your list and print that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2.x use `repr()`.  Python 3.x use `repr()` if you don't mind non-ASCII Unicode in the result, or `ascii()` if you do:

```
>>> a=1             # integer
>>> class X: pass
...
>>> x=X()           # class
>>> y='\u5000'      # Unicode string
>>> z=b'\xa0'       # non-ASCII byte string
>>> ' '.join(ascii(i) for i in (a,x,y,z))
"1 <__main__.X object at 0x0000000002974B38> '\\u5000' b'\\xa0'"
```

Example of differences between 2.X and 3.X `repr()`, and 3.X `ascii()`:

```
>>> # Python 3
>>> s = 'pingüino' # Unicode string
>>> s
'pingüino'
>>> repr(s)
"'pingüino'"
>>> print(repr(s))
'pingüino'
>>> ascii(s)
"'ping\\xfcino'"
>>> print(ascii(s))
'ping\xfcino'    

>>> # Python 2
>>> s = u'pingüino'
>>> s
u'ping\xfcino'
>>> repr(s)
"u'ping\\xfcino'"
>>> print(repr(s))
u'ping\xfcino'
```

Comment: To clarify, from `repr()`'s docstring, it returns the canonical string representation of the object. So imagine whatever you print to the console, e.g. a class reference, list, or anything else, it will turn into a string.

Comment: Where do you get this `ascii()` function from? If I try `ascii('something')` I get  `NameError: name 'ascii' is not defined`. I tried importing it and searching around for it, but I can't find any mention of such a function. Any more tips?

Comment: @kramer65, `ascii()` is Python 3.x only.  It works like `repr()` on Python 2.x.  `repr()` on Python 3.x will display printable non-ASCII when supported by the output encoding, making it easier for languages other than English to read the output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm so into Python 2.7, that I didn't even think of the possibility of Python 3. Thanks for pointing that out. Since most libraries are now ported I might consider starting with Python 3 with upcoming projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `join`ing with a unicode object instead..

```
u' '.join(unicode(x) for x in thelist)
```

Or what you had before will work fine in python3. Just be sure to:

1. decode early
2. unicode everywhere
3. encode late

For more details see [this talk](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: That doesn't always work, for example `unicode('ü')` leads to a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. Any other idea?

Comment: I tried running a file which contains two lines: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and 
`print unicode('ü')`, but I still get the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: Sorry. You need to be using unicode objects. Either do `print u'ü'` or if you must use a string you will have to decode it with  `print 'ü'.decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining the ternary operator with your current one-liner. Also `join` works just fine with a generator, so I don't think you need to create the list. Something like

```
' '.join(x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, basestring) else str(x)
         for x in the_list)
```